# tidyverse: count number of a specific level when summarizing

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, tidyverse, summarize

I would like, when summarizing after grouping, to count the number of a specific level of another factor.

In the working example below, I would like to count the number of `"male"` levels in each group. I've tried many things with count, tally and so on but cannot find a straightforward and neat way to do it.

```
df <- data.frame(Group=replicate(20, sample(c("A","B"), 1)),
                 Value=rnorm(20),
                 Factor=replicate(20, sample(c("male","female"), 1)))
df %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  summarize(Value = mean(Value),
            n_male = ???)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Maybe `with(df, table(Factor))` or `with(df, table(Factor, Group))` would also be of interest.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can use `sum` on a `logical` `vector` i.e. `Factor == "male"`.  The `TRUE/FALSE` will be coerced to `1/0` to get the frequency of 'male' elements when we do the `sum`

```
df %>%
   group_by(Group) %>% 
   summarise(Value = mean(Value), 
             n_male = sum(Factor=="male"))
```

Comment: To add to that, you could also apply a filter to the variable `Factor` : `n_male = length(Factor[Factor=="male"]))`